# Puppet module Getting Syntax error at '{'; expected '}'

Tags: linux, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am trying to implement this https://github.com/andytinycat/puppet-rhnsatellite. I have configured the username and password under the `module/rhnsatellite/manifest/init.pp`

`class rhnsatellite(
    $server_url  = "https://test.example.com/XMLRPC",
    $username = "testuserver",
    $password = "test@123"
    ) 
    {
    file {'/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/rhn.conf':
    owner   => root,
    group   => root,
    mode    => 0600,
    content => template('rhnsatellite/rhn.conf.erb')
    }
    }`

I am new to puppet and I dont know to how to call the satelliterepo in site.pp , I get a syntax error when I run it on the client machine

`node 'client' {
    include vmware
    class { rhnsatellite :
    satelliterepo {channel => 'base-stash-el6',
    }
    include sudo
    include sssd
    include hardening
    include base-httpd
    include hpom
    class { sshd: }
    }`
I get the following error when I run in client

`` [root@client puppet]# puppet agent --test --noop  --environment=test
    Info: Retrieving plugin
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/tenant.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/windows.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/log_exists_jbossecaps.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/custom_auth_conf.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/concat_basedir.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/cluster.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/postgres_default_version.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/dtap.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/puppetdb_server_status.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/ip6tables_version.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/root_home.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/log_exists_jbosshouse.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/iptables_persistent_version.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/gateway.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/iptables_version.rb
    Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
    Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER:          Could not parse for environment test: Syntax error at '{'; expected '}' at /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/environments/test/manifests/site.pp:1157 on node client
    Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
    Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
    [root@client puppet]#` ``

Comment: Have you completed the Training VM course?

Answer (score 1):

You should not touch module/rhnsatellite/manifest/init.pp. Just leave it as it is.
To override default params of a rhnsatellite class put it in your site.pp like this:

```
class { "rhnsatellite":
    server_url  => "https://test.example.com/XMLRPC",
    username => "testuserver",
    password => "test@123",
}
```

And remove this part completely:

```
class { rhnsatellite :
    satelliterepo {channel => 'base-stash-el6',
}
```